# A large number of JetDirect firmware updates - what issues do they address?

Tags: hp, update, print-server, firmware

HP recently released [a large number of firmware updates for JetDirect devices](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpj07429&docLocale=en_US). There is no changelog provided. Curiously, many obsolete (e.g., 802.11b) devices are in the list, and the last time a firmware update was provided for some of these was 2004. The devices range from 10/100 ethernet to 802.11b/g print servers, EIO, MIO, and LIO. Does this batch of updates address some set of security vulnerabilities (e.g., SSLv3, POODLE or other documented CVEs) or introduce new functionality (e.g., TLS or WPA2)?

**Update**
Based on information in the page supplied in the accepted answer, there were several security updates and new features introduced in these firmware updates. Among those for the 280m, these were the updates I was most interested in, as they appear to several SSL vulnerabilities and add WPA compatibility:

- Automatic IP Addressing
- Ethernet Locally Administered Addressing (LAA)
- Import/Export of Certificates for SSL
- CERT Vulnerability Note [VU#412115](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/412115) has been fixed
- FTP and DHCP improvements, SPX and TCP improvements.
- Wi-Fi Certification for 802.11b and WPA for the 680n (J6058A), 380x (J6061A), 280m (J6044A) 802.11b wireless print servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched HP's website...

http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpj02930#N10473

[image]

[image]

[image]

That is all.

Comment: Thank you, that got me in the right area. The specific information I was looking for was on a [related page](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpj07475#N114A4). I will include a summary in the question.

Comment: Update: In 2017, the site that hosted the information in this answer was decommissioned. The most up-to-date firmware documentation is available [here](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/jetdirect/firmware/current_firmware_readme.pdf).